# Old, oily, wet gasoline. What to do with it?

Tags: gasoline

I have a small amount (less than a gallon) of gasoline that's been in a can for two years. It has oil mixed in for 2-stroke engines.

The can sprung a leak and rainwater leaked inside. Probably only a teaspoon or two, but I can't know for sure.

How to get rid of it? Should I burn it off? Can I just mix it with more gas and use it?

---

**Edit:**

I found a good, unorthodox solution. I stored my gas cans in an unlocked shed in my back yard.  Someone came by and stole them!  Your mileage may vary :)

Comment: If your into camping, you could always use it to get a camp fire(s) going.

Comment: Just be careful not to pour the gas while the fire is going.  My grandfather almost died that way.

Comment: Hi DucatiKiller! I don't see this as a duplicate. Motor oil is intended as a lubricant, is thick, and is much more hazardous to burn. Gasoline is intended as a fuel source, acts as a solvent, and burns fairly cleanly (relative to motor oil, anyway). I believe the disposal methods would vary greatly between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to mix and re-use as you are not sure how much water is in it. If there is too much water this can damage your engine. It's not a lot of gas. $2-$3 is not worth risking possible damages.

If you want to properly get rid of it, check with your local recycling centers to see if they accept old gas. Or just burn it off.

Answer (score 5):

Take it to your local waste / recycling centre and leave it with their oils disposal section.

It you have a suitable multi-fuel heater you could burn it in that but I wouldn't simply burn it itself or use it in a vehicle.

Comment: If you just let it stand some time, whatever water will settle down to the bottom over time (not miscible with oil or gas). Even so, I agree it would not be wise to use it in a vehicle, unless the said vehicle was equipped with a water decanter on the fuel line. This is more common on diesel-engined trucks and heavy equipment than in cars.